# Error loading page Domain:undefined Error Code: -1 Description:net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I am still generating this error for an expo start command and to view a page with a leaflet map - -works fine on IoS and my colleagues.

The error is also in console log as follows:

```
Encountered an error loading page, Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "code": -1,
  "description": "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND",
  "loading": false,
  "target": 19,
  "title": "",
  "url": "file:///android_asset/leaflet.html",
}
```

at http://10.4.208.108:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:170103:20 in onLoadingError

I have added the following potential correction:

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1050

but, for some reason my expo start keeps failing. I am using a Red Hat distro and thought it might be my system -- so ran in root and still have errors.

Any suggestions deeply appreciated, thanks
Karen

I have tried adding the following to my manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sjaws">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="44.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@prince_ubs/SJAWS"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.sjaws"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```